# Android: radio group in list view not working

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiogroup

- When i click the radio group from the first item all the
  corresponding items should be selected when the check box is checked
  if the check box is not checked then the corresponding items radio
  button should not be checked.
- if i click in between then first item    radio button should be
  deselect else if i click the unchecked radio    button the check box
  should be checked and radio button also be    checked. This is what i
  want to achieve in this.

My problem from the below code is when i click the first item all the items getting selected but if i click another item in between the first item is getting deselected and the button which i clicked is re positioned

[image: List View with radio button]

**TeacherAssessmentFragmentChild.java**

```
package com.example.playit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class TeacherAssessmentFragmentChild extends Fragment {
static Context context;
ArrayList<TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer> assessmentContainer=new ArrayList<>();
View rootView ;
ListView lstassessment;
TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildListAdapter listAdapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teacher_asseessment_view_fragment_child,
                container, false);
        Initialize();   
        context = TeacherAssessmentFragment.context;        
        assessmentContainer.add(new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer("Chapter", "-1"));
        assessmentContainer.add(new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer("Chp - 1 Algebra", "1"));
        assessmentContainer.add(new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer("Chp - 2 Trignomentry", "-1"));
        assessmentContainer.add(new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer("Chp - 3 Integration", "4"));
        assessmentContainer.add(new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer("Chp - 4 Differentiation", "3"));
        assessmentContainer.add(new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer("Chp - 5 Abacus", "2"));
        assessmentContainer.add(new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer("Chp - 6 Numbersystem", "-1"));
        assessmentContainer.add(new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer("Chp - 7 Algebra", "-1"));
        assessmentContainer.add(new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer("Chp - 8 Algebra", "2"));
        listAdapter=new TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildListAdapter(context, 0, assessmentContainer);
        lstassessment.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return rootView;
}
public void Initialize()    {
    lstassessment=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_assessment_view_fragment_clild_assessment_list);

}

}
```

**TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer.java**

```
 package com.example.playit;

public class TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer {

String chapterName,moduleSelected;
Boolean ismoduleActive;


public TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer(String chapterName,
        String moduleSelected) {
    super();
    this.chapterName = chapterName;
    this.moduleSelected = moduleSelected;
    if(moduleSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))
        ismoduleActive=false;
    else
        ismoduleActive=true;
}

public Boolean getIsmoduleActive() {
    return ismoduleActive;
}

public void setIsmoduleActive(Boolean ismoduleActive) {
    this.ismoduleActive = ismoduleActive;
}

public String getChapterName() {
    return chapterName;
}

public String getModuleSelected() {
    return moduleSelected;
}

public void setModuleSelected(String moduleSelected) {
    this.moduleSelected = moduleSelected;
}
}
```

**TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildListAdapter**

```
package com.example.playit;

import java.util.ArrayList;

   import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildListAdapter extends
    ArrayAdapter<TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer>  {
static Context context;
static ArrayList<TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer> container = new ArrayList<>();
ViewHolder holder;
static int checkBoxCount = 0, radioCount = 0, selectedPosition = -1;


public TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildListAdapter(Context context,
        int resource,
        ArrayList<TeacherAssessmentFragmentChildContainer> container) {
    super(context, resource, container);
    this.context = context;
    this.container = container;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // Count=Size of ArrayList.
    return container.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getCount();
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView txvchapterName;
    CheckBox ckbselectName;
    RadioGroup rgassessment;
    RadioButton assessment1, assessment2, assessment3, assessment4,
            assessment5;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // System.out.println("getview:" + position + " " + convertView);
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater
                .inflate(
                        R.layout.teacher_assessment_view_fragment_child_list_adapter,
                        parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txvchapterName = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_view_fragment_child_list_adapter_chapter);
        holder.ckbselectName = (CheckBox) row
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_view_fragment_child_list_adapter_select);
        holder.rgassessment = (RadioGroup) row
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_view_fragment_child_list_adapter_assessment_group);
        holder.assessment1 = (RadioButton) holder.rgassessment
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_view_fragment_child_list_adapter_assessment1);
        holder.assessment2 = (RadioButton) holder.rgassessment
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_view_fragment_child_list_adapter_assessment2);
        holder.assessment3 = (RadioButton) holder.rgassessment
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_view_fragment_child_list_adapter_assessment3);
        holder.assessment4 = (RadioButton) holder.rgassessment
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_view_fragment_child_list_adapter_assessment4);
        holder.assessment5 = (RadioButton) holder.rgassessment
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_view_fragment_child_list_adapter_assessment5);
        row.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    if (position == 0) {
        holder.assessment1.setButtonDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
        holder.assessment2.setButtonDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
        holder.assessment3.setButtonDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
        holder.assessment4.setButtonDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
        holder.assessment5.setButtonDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
        holder.assessment1.setText("");
        holder.assessment2.setText("");
        holder.assessment3.setText("");
        holder.assessment4.setText("");
        holder.assessment5.setText("");
    } else {
        holder.assessment1.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
        holder.assessment2.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
        holder.assessment3.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
        holder.assessment4.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
        holder.assessment5.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
        holder.assessment1.setText("M1");
        holder.assessment2.setText("M2");
        holder.assessment3.setText("M3");
        holder.assessment4.setText("M4");
        holder.assessment5.setText("M5");
    }
    holder.ckbselectName.setTag(position);
    holder.rgassessment.setTag(position);
    SetCheckedRbn(container.get(position).getModuleSelected());
    SetCheckedChb(container.get(position).ismoduleActive);
    holder.ckbselectName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
            System.out.println("selectedPosition : "+selectedPosition);
            System.out.println("container.get(selectedPosition).getIsmoduleActive()  : "+container.get(selectedPosition).getIsmoduleActive());
            if(selectedPosition==0){
                for(int i=0;i<container.size();i++){
                    if(!container.get(i).getIsmoduleActive()){
                        container.get(i).setIsmoduleActive(true);
                        container.get(i).setModuleSelected("0");
                    }
                    else    {
                        container.get(i).setIsmoduleActive(false);
                        container.get(i).setModuleSelected("-1");                       
                    }
                }
            }
            else    {
                if(!container.get(selectedPosition).getIsmoduleActive()){
                    container.get(selectedPosition).setIsmoduleActive(true);
                    container.get(selectedPosition).setModuleSelected("0");
                }
                else    {
                    container.get(selectedPosition).setIsmoduleActive(false);
                    container.get(selectedPosition).setModuleSelected("-1");                        
                }
            }

            System.out.println("container.get(selectedPosition).getIsmoduleActive()  : "+container.get(selectedPosition).getIsmoduleActive());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    holder.txvchapterName.setText(container.get(position).getChapterName());
    holder.rgassessment
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    selectedPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();
                    View radioButtonView = group.findViewById(checkedId); 
                    RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);
                    int idx = group.indexOfChild(radioButtonView);
                    if (selectedPosition == 0 && checkedRadioButton.isChecked() ) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++) {
                            if (container.get(i).getIsmoduleActive() ||  i==0 ){
                                container.get(i).setModuleSelected("" + idx);
                            }
                            else if(i!=0){
                                container.get(i).setModuleSelected("-1");
                                container.get(i).setIsmoduleActive(false);
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    else if(selectedPosition !=0){
                        container.get(selectedPosition).setIsmoduleActive(
                                true);
                        container.get(selectedPosition).setModuleSelected(
                                "" + idx);
                    }
                    checkrb();
                }
            });
    return row;
}

public void SetCheckedRbn(String str) {
    switch (str) {
    case "0":
        holder.assessment1.setChecked(true);
        break;
    case "1":
        holder.assessment2.setChecked(true);
        break;
    case "2":
        holder.assessment3.setChecked(true);
        break;
    case "3":
        holder.assessment4.setChecked(true);
        break;
    case "4":
        holder.assessment5.setChecked(true);
        break;
    default:
        holder.assessment1.setChecked(false);
        holder.assessment2.setChecked(false);
        holder.assessment3.setChecked(false);
        holder.assessment4.setChecked(false);
        holder.assessment5.setChecked(false);
        break;
    }
}

public void SetCheckedChb(Boolean isactive) {
    if (isactive)
        holder.ckbselectName.setChecked(true);
    else
        holder.ckbselectName.setChecked(false);
}

public void checkrb()   {
    int rbcount=0,chcount=0;
    String str="";
    for(int i=0;i<container.size();i++) {
        str=container.get(i).getModuleSelected();
        if(str!="-1"){
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<container.size() && str!="";i++)  {
        if(str.equals(container.get(i).getModuleSelected()) && container.get(i).getIsmoduleActive()){
            rbcount++;
            str=container.get(i).getModuleSelected();
        }
        if(container.get(i).getIsmoduleActive())
            chcount++;
    }
    if(rbcount!=chcount)
        container.get(0).setModuleSelected("-1");   
    else
        container.get(0).setModuleSelected(str);
    if(rbcount==container.size())
        container.get(0).setIsmoduleActive(true);
    else
        container.get(0).setIsmoduleActive(false);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void checkchb()  {
    int chcount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<container.size();i++) {
        if(container.get(i).getIsmoduleActive())
            chcount++;
    }
    if(chcount==(container.size()-1)){
        container.get(0).setIsmoduleActive(true);
    }
    else
        container.get(0).setIsmoduleActive(false);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```